# Customize a report with filter on parent object

Tags: reporting

I have an object child_to_account__c and a report is already created on this object.
Now, I have to include a filter in this report such that the user can enter any value they wish and execute the report.
But, here the filter field is on Account obect which has lookup relationship with child_to_account__c object.

Can you please guide, how can I modify the existing report such that I fulfill the requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Report Type" determines which objects' fields are available in the report (for displaying and for filters). To see the report type of an existing report, go into the "customize" or "edit" screen, and at the top left you should see the report type.  It looks something like "Accounts with Opportunities" or "Child_to_Accounts with or without Accounts".

If the Account object is not available, then you will have to recreate the report using a different report type.  You select that when you start a fresh report.  If the combination of objects you need is not available, you can create a custom "report type" in Setup and choose your own objects, but there are limitations depending on how they are related.

Once you are using the correct report type, you should be able to filter on Account fields.

Comment: so, in this case I have to create a new customized report and I can't customize the existing report to support this functionality ?